# bash scripting - csv column modification

Tags: bash, csv

Getting a little bit paranoid with bash tonight, trying to extract some data in one line if possible

The file line looks like this:

37,140101,0305,5.24e-008,0.0,0,+7.2,+8.4,1.2,250,997.1,46.7,23.7

And by using the following command i get the lines that interest me:

```
grep 140101 `find /home/rsync/inc/37/ -name '*.dat'` | \
awk -F ":" '{ print $2  }' | awk -F "," '{ print $1","$2","$3","$4  }
```

which gets me to here:
0433,20130228,235010,10,5.604e-08

I need to be converting the date and time (140101,0305) to (20140101,030500) - adding 4 digit year and seconds (00) to time.

I could loop it of course and format with the date command, but i was wandering if there is any way to convert "on the go".
For time i will possibly go with a static "00". Could do the same and add "20" in front of the year and leave it work until it is someone else problem, as I will be long gone by then! But it's just too ugly :)

Any ideas? thanks for looking.

Comment: Why can't use just append that in the second `awk` command? (not sure you need two, but input isn't clear) Also, assuming you're using gnu grep, you can just use the `--include` option and `-R` for recursive, rather than using `find`.

Comment: It is not clear from where you should take the missing pieces of information (year and seconds)

Comment: Seconds are just 00, the exact second is not recoverable, and they are not important anyway. Went for the easy solution after all to add "20" in front of the year. In 86 years someone should look into that :-) Followed BroSlow's advice for grep -r --include rather than passing find results. Works like a clock.